# Single selection tag (Foursquare-CollectionPicker)

Tags: android

I am trying to do single selection(selecting only one tag at a time) of tags using this [library](https://github.com/anton46/Foursquare-CollectionPicker) but this library does not support single selection at a time hence i tryed to use below solution :

> Screenshot :

[image]

Step 1: Clear all selection

```
items.add(new Item("1", getResources().getString(R.string.receipe_type_all),false));
        items.add(new Item("2", getResources().getString(R.string.receipe_type_veg),false));
        items.add(new Item("3", getResources().getString(R.string.receipe_type_non_veg),false));
        items.add(new Item("4", getResources().getString(R.string.receipe_type_both),false));
        items.add(new Item("5", getResources().getString(R.string.receipe_type_seafood),false));
        items.add(new Item("6", getResources().getString(R.string.receipe_type_drinks),false));
```

Step 2 : select a particular tag last clicked

```
 resetItems.set(0, new Item("1", getResources().getString(R.string.receipe_type_all), true));
 mTagPicker.setItems(items);
 mTagPicker.drawItemView();
```

But this does not work and only works if item is deleted or added into picker collection , i want to know how to change status of checked and unchecked item programtically without changing size of items in picker.